# Items in Combobox gets added

Tags: c#, winforms

I've two radiobuttons and a single checkbox.

Items in checkbox will pop up according to the radiobutton selected.

The problem is when I click the second radiobutton after clicking the first radiobutton, Combobox pops us all the values from both radiobutton 1 and 2.

```
    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (string apacservers in Properties.Settings.Default.B)
        {             
            comboBox1.Items.Add(ItemsB);
        }                    
    }

    private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (string europeservers in Properties.Settings.Default.A)
        {               
            comboBox1.Items.Add(ItemsA);
        }               
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Clear it first? `comboBox1.Items.Clear();`

Comment: And you need to do `if(radioButton1.Checked){ ... add items ... };` That only notifies you of the check *changing*, not if it's checked or not.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `comboBox1.Items.Clear();` before both of your foreachs.

Comment: If I add comboBox1.Items.Clear(); only the last value of string collection is popping up

Comment: Sorry, I gave the wrong answer and edited it